# How to dynamically set ng-model to correspond with object property

Tags: html, json, angularjs

In a certain json file, there is only one object that will ever exist in the array. This object, however, has an unknown amount of properties.

```
[{"red": 14, "green": 12, "orange": 1, "yellow": 11, "blue": 9}]
```

This object is called "items". This is my form:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form class="idea item">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in items[0]" >
        <label>{{key}}</label>
        <input type="range" value="{{value}}" min="0" max="15"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" />
</form>
</div>
```

When I hit submit on the form, however, the data sent is always the data that was initially set in the inputs: `[{"red": 14, "green": 12, "orange": 1, "yellow": 11, "blue": 9}]`

As an example, if I set all inputs to 0, how do I get it to send `[{"red": 0, "green": 0, "orange": 0, "yellow": 0, "blue": 0}]` ?

The `save()` function basically consists of:

```
$http.put(url, $scope.items);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like variable keys in javascript use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) in the ng-model as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
<input type="range" ng-model="items[0][key]" min="0" max="15"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N6mEv/)

Comment: Works, except `items[0][key]` should be just `items[key]` because the `ng-repeat` already specifies `(key, value) in items[0]`

Comment: @rosciood which is the angularjs version used? the fiddle seems to be working fine

Comment: I'm using 1.1.1, that may be the problem with my end, however I'm just happy it works. And you are correct, the jsfiddle you provided does work fine. Thank you!